# Parsing a XML file with Perl XMLSimple

Tags: xml, perl, hash, xml-simple

I'm trying to parse a *`XML`*-like file with the following structure:

Edit:
I tried to omit most of the huge xml file to simplify everything but c/p-ed wrongly. Here's the full file (900kb!) that actually has this issue: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3ustNI1qZh1UURrYWZJQk0wVlU/edit?usp=sharing

```
<CIM CIMVERSION="2.0" DTDVERSION="2.0">

  <DECLARATION>
    <DECLGROUP>
      <LOCALNAMESPACEPATH>
        <NAMESPACE NAME="signalingsystem"/>
      </LOCALNAMESPACEPATH>

      <VALUE.OBJECT>
        <INSTANCE CLASSNAME="SharedGtTranslator">
          <PROPERTY NAME="Name" TYPE="string">
            <VALUE>AUC$4,1,6,4,26202*-->AUC RemoteSPC: 300 SSN: 10</VALUE>
          </PROPERTY>
          <PROPERTY NAME="NatureOfAddress" TYPE="sint32">
            <VALUE>4</VALUE>
          </PROPERTY>
        </INSTANCE>
      </VALUE.OBJECT>

      <VALUE.OBJECT>
        <INSTANCE CLASSNAME="SharedGtTranslator">
          <PROPERTY NAME="Name" TYPE="string">
            <VALUE>AUC$4,2,6,4,26202*-->AUC AUC LocalSPC: 410 SSN: 10</VALUE>
          </PROPERTY>
          <PROPERTY NAME="NatureOfAddress" TYPE="sint32">
            <VALUE>4</VALUE>
          </PROPERTY>
            <VALUE>2</VALUE>
          </PROPERTY>
        </INSTANCE>
      </VALUE.OBJECT>
    </DECLGROUP>

  </DECLARATION>
</CIM>
```

I'm using XMLSimple to parse that structure.
I need to get all the Values for the PROPERTY `NAME="Name"` if `CLASSNAME="SharedGtTranslator"`.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
# use module
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

my $file1 = $ARGV[0];
# create object
my $xml = new XML::Simple;

# read XML file
my $data = $xml->XMLin($file1);
foreach my $object (@{$data->{DECLARATION}->{DECLGROUP}->{'VALUE.OBJECT'}}) {
        if ($object->{INSTANCE}->{CLASSNAME} eq 'SharedGtTranslator') {
                foreach my $property (@{$object->{INSTANCE}->{PROPERTY}}) {
                        if ($property->{NAME} eq 'Name') {
                                print $property->{VALUE} . "\n";
                        }
                }

        }
}
```

Getting

> "Pseudo-hashes are deprecated"

and nothing happens.

Help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Your XML has a missing PROPERTY tag. When I fixed that, the code you supplied works, except for an uninitialized warning.

Comment: Actually that was a mistake from my side. I tried to omit most of the huge xml file to simplify everything but c/p-ed wrongly. Here's the full file (900kb!): https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3ustNI1qZh1UURrYWZJQk0wVlU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The cryptic "Pseudo-hashes are deprecated" message occurs when you try to index into an arrayref as if it were a hashref.  I recommend the brief but informative [Perl references tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) I also concur with @Borodin's advice to use XML::LibXML instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine for me as it stands. Is that the full program? There is no use of pseudo-hashes in that code.

The only problem I can see is that your XML data isn't well-formed. There is a spurious

```
  <VALUE>2</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
```

at the end of the last `INSTANCE` element. Once this is fixed your program runs fine.

`XML::Simple` seems to be working for you, so it's probably appropriate to stick with it. But I don't generally recommend that people use this module. It can be far from simple to get working, and the structure it builds doesn't fully reflect the XML data, so something like
[`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig)
or
[`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML)
is often much better.

---

**Update**

Working with your real data, the structure generated by `XML::Simple` looks quite unlike what is generated for the short example. There are arrays intermingled with the hashes that weren't there before.

This program seems to generate what you need. It produces 170 lines of output.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Simple;

my $file1 = 'active_7v19.om.cim';

my $xml  = new XML::Simple;
my $data = $xml->XMLin($file1);

for my $declgroup (@{ $data->{DECLARATION}{DECLGROUP} }) {

    foreach my $object (@{ $declgroup->{'VALUE.OBJECT'} }) {

        my $instance   = $object->{INSTANCE};
        my $classname  = $instance->{CLASSNAME};
        my $properties = $instance->{PROPERTY};

        next unless $classname eq 'SharedGtTranslator';

        for my $property (@$properties) {

            my $name  = $property->{NAME};
            my $value = $property->{VALUE};

            print $value, "\n" if $name eq 'Name';
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am more sure now that you would be better off with a "real" XML library. THis code uses `XML::LibXML` to produce the same output.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $file1, no_blanks => 1);

my @properties = $doc->findnodes('//INSTANCE[@CLASSNAME = "SharedGtTranslator"]/PROPERTY[@NAME = "Name"]');

for my $property (@properties) {
    print $property->textContent('VALUE'), "\n";
}
```

All the work is done by the XPath expression, which selects all `PROPERTY` elements with a `NAME` attribute of `Name` that are children of an `INSTANCE` element anywhere in the document that has a `CLASSNAME` attribute of `SharedGtTranslator`. The subsequent `for` loop prints the value of the `VALUE` element within each `PROPERTY`. It is clearly a lot more concise, and it is also faster to run, and more flexible if you need to extract different information.

Comment: Actually that was a mistake from my side.
I tried to omit most of the huge xml file to simplify everything but c/p-ed wrongly.
Here's the full file (900kb!): https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3ustNI1qZh1UURrYWZJQk0wVlU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for showing the full data. I have added an update to my anaswer that shows a working program that uses `XML::Simple` as well as a version with `XML::LibXML` that I recommend you use instead.

Comment: Thanks, the LibXML seems indeed a much cleaner solution. Am stuck at LibXML 1.58 so couldn't use load_xml.

Comment: Uh, perhaps i'm asking too much, but how would you output the whole VALUE.OBJECT element that matches and retain its XML format?

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is not well-formed. I get parse errors. Your very last Property, you close, but don't open (or name, as a result). After that, in Perl 5.16, it prints:

```
AUC$4,1,6,4,26202*-->AUC RemoteSPC: 300 SSN: 10
AUC$4,2,6,4,26202*-->AUC AUC LocalSPC: 410 SSN: 10
```

Of course this is with XML::Simple 2.20.